# Retaining View between one view controller and UAModalPanel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, view

I have two view controllers named as `firstvc`, `secondvc`. I have a subview in the `firstvc`, it looks like a form which has textfields. In `firstvc` there is a button to maximize that subview.

When I click on that, I am adding that subview to `secondvc` and I am presenting `secondvc` view in `UAModalPanel`. If I close that `secondvc`, `firstvc` should appear. My problem is that I was unable to retain that subview. It means when I close `secondvc`, `firstvc` subview is disappearing.

Can you suggest how to retain that subview between two view controllers?

```
-(IBAction)maximize:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *newview   = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];


    [newview.view addSubview:subview];

    UAModalPanel  *modalpanelobject = [[UAModalPanel alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];    

    [modalpanelobject.contentView addSubview:newview.view];

    [self.view addSubview:modalpanelobject];


    [modalpanelobject showFromPoint:self.view.center];

}
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using to show/close the `secondvc` and the way you add the subview to `firstvc`?

Comment: hey i have added that maximize code,for closing modal panel view it provides close button automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer behind [UAModalPanel](http://github.com/coneybeare/uamodalpanel). The panel does nothing to mess with the view hierarchy of views that are not added to the `contentView` so this problem probably would exist even without it. I would subclass the first controller's view and place a breakpoint in the `dealloc` and `removeFromSuperview` methods to see what is removing the view, when and why.

Comment: The thing is without taking modal panel, if i present secondvc its working fine.If i give to modal panel its not retaining.

Comment: One thing i want to tell you is i kept manual close button to hide the modal panel, when i come back view is not reloading but again when i click on maximize button its coming along with subview. I think modal panel is not releasing that subview when i hide it.is there any relation with that?

Comment: - "The thing is without taking modal panel, if i present secondvc its working fine.If i give to modal panel its not retaining." - That is correct, why would it retain it? Your calling controller should retain it if you are interested in keeping it around. If I were you though, I would not pass the view around between controllers, but recreate it or copy it.

Comment: If i recreate the view,i have to maintain so many outlets, delegates present in the views.Thats why iam trying in this way.I have a doubt that if i copy that view when i edit any fields, the data will be replicated or not? can u suggest me how to do that. otherwise i think if i release modal panel object, it will reload.But iam doing it in iOS5,  so once i hide that modal panel how to release it?

Comment: Hey i resolved it finally!!!!  what i did is i have a view which has subview as scrollview. This whole view aim adding to cell content view.so when i maximize it iam giving scrollview to maximized view.when i hide model panel , iam just adding that scrollview outlet as [view addSubView:scrollview] thats it. while that view any how added in cell content view.So even with out reloading grid view also its working...

Answer (score 0):

Look,
The concept is 
There are three view you can consider.

1. Child View (ScrollView in your case)
2. Parent View 1 (GridCell)
3. Parent View 2 ('Maximized View)

What you are doing is  when

1.You are maximizing the Child view

At that time you are taking the **Child View from Grid Cell to Maximized View.**

2.Now in reverse when you are closing the Maxized View.

**Correct**:At that time you SHOULD take the **Child View from Maximized View to Grid Cell.**

for doing that you can not find your Child View in Grid Cells.

Best Regards.

Comment: I have a separate outlet for scrollview, so without taking from grid cell also i can add it to maximized view or grid cell.I have done in that way also, still its not working.

Comment: Hey when you are closing maximise view you  are reloading the grids fine?

Comment: While reloading I suppose you are adding scroll view to grid cell ?

Comment: bye for today...m thats what I think, otherwise appreciate your serious efforts.

Comment: I have  retain property to scrollview outlet, so while reloading. Iam just adding that scrollview to cell content view without taking from maximized view.

Comment: Hey i resolved it finally!!!!  what i did is i have a view which has subview as scrollview. This whole view aim adding to cell content view.so when i maximize it iam giving scrollview to maximized view.when i hide model panel , iam just adding that scrollview outlet as [view addSubView:scrollview] thats it. while that view any how added in cell content view.So even with out reloading grid view also its working...